Can't get custom style working in pandoc for odt output
According to the doc, custom-style for odt output should be straigthforward in Pandoc, without the need for any extension.
However, I can't get them applied. The following styles don't get written in the xml of the odt file, while using docx output it works:
MD source document:
### header

bla

this is a <span custom-style="Anote">custom style span</span>

::: {custom-style="Poetry"}
| A Bird came down the Walk---
| He did not know I saw---
:::

::: {custom-style="bluestyle"} 
I'm blue
:::

# My Header {style="Header 7"}
scscscs

this is a <span custom-style="mystyle">custom style span</span>

Pandoc Command:
pandoc test_input.md   -o test_output.odt
Versions:

pandoc 3.5.1
ubuntu 22.04


Where is the programming aspect?
